# I'm working on android project, I want to check whether the password and re-enter password does match or not if it doesn't I want to stop right there

Tags: android

I'm working on Android project, I want to check whether the password and re-enter password does match or not if it doesn't I want to stop right there. I did:

```
System.exit(0);
```

this `System.exit(0);` function takes me to the different page but I want to stay where I am now.

```
break;
finish();
```

I tried break and finish they did not work either. any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: What does `stop right there` logically mean?  Do you want to freeze the user from doing anything?  I think just providing feedback, and possibly greying out the submit button, should be enough, no?

Comment: Rather than 'stop right there' you should show a dialog or message to user

Comment: explain what you mean by  "I want to stop right there". if you don't want to exit or finish, then just don't call the codes?

Comment: Hi, I don't mean "stop right there" in code, sorry for the missunderstanding. What I'm saying is that I wnat to alert the user that they input password doesn't match. System.exit() exited the page and finish() didn't work code still passed through the line break; says out of loop or switch.

Answer (score 0):

try this snippet code.

```
    EditText passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
    EditText rePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rePassword);

    if(!passwordText.getText().toString().equals(rePassword.getText().toString())){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password must same",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
       //do some thing.
    }
```

hope it help

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that but i want to do somethig like       if(!passwordText.getText().toString().equals(rePassword.getText().toString())){ Toast.maketext(this, "Password doesn't match", Toast.length_long).show(); brek, or System.exit} I wnat to stop the program here. How do i do that?

Comment: do you mean like force exit?

Comment: No, I want stay in the same page and alert user that they are typing two different password.

Comment: i just edited my answer, i think that enough for make the application not doing anything.